# GAE dashboard with traffic allocation segmented by service and version

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, dashboard

I could find no guidance in the GCP documentation. As far as I understood, dashboards should be based on metrics tracked and made available by GCP (or user defined), but I found no such metric for traffic allocation, nor a way to track it myself.

The dashboard I need should be based on this view and it should include only the services that are currently serving.

[image]

Also, it should be grouped by Service. I believe a stacked barplot should suffice.

Extra: I should be able to export it to outside GCP.

Thanks.

Comment: I would highly suggest to file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/) to Enhanced Traffic Allocation Visualization For Google App Engine.